# android access EditText data in a new activity after onClick

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm a new android programmer, I'm using android studio. I'm creating a grade calculator application. I let the user enter in grading scale in the first layout/activity then I can jump to second layout/activity. But I'm not sure how to access to that data in my second activity file. I have a text view in my second activity, and I'm testing if I can access to the edit view data in first activity by changing the text view in my second activity but I failed. Please help, thanks.

Here are my activity codes.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button_next:
            scale = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.gradeScale);
            String getInput = scale.getText().toString();
            TextView gc_scale=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.what);
            //gc_scale.setText(getInput);

            Intent i = new Intent(this, classEnterActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("scale",getInput);
            //i.putExtra("scaleG",getInput);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is my second activity file, I want to change the textView output to be the string I entered in first activity. Sometimes my app crashes.

```
public class classEnterActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.course);

    //View ContinueButton = findViewById(R.id.button_next);
    //ContinueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){

    TextView output=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.what);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String str=intent.getStringExtra("scale");
    output.setText(str);
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button_next:

            break;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Whats the error? Just a NullPointer I'll guess - Note: [mcve]

Comment: I think my question would become how can I add onClick function after set contentview. So, if I un-comment these two lines in my second file                   :      View ContinueButton = findViewById(R.id.button_next);
        ContinueButton.setOnClickListener(this);                                                               When I run my app, it says "Unfortunately, the App has stopped"

Comment: Go to your log. What is the error from the crash?

Comment: Yes, null pointer exception

Comment: You need to paste the stacktrace. I can see you have asked other questions - you need to read my link above.

Comment: Without any stacktrace to go by I can only *guess*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that `getIntent()` is returning null

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView output=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.what);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        String str=intent.getStringExtra("scale");
        output.setText(str);
        ...
    }
}
```

There's also a chance that `output` is null or even `v`, you can fix those errors with similar null checks

Answer (score 0):

OK people. Thank you all for answering my question. I just figured it out by myself. Though not sure how, but I basically rewrite my second activity file. check this website for format: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

I guess I made some stupid issues but I'm not sure what they are.